# Create an OSX app programmatically loading just one website by default

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I would like to create an OSX app programmatically that loads just one website by default, no address bar. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Automator to achieve this:

[image: source code]
[image: the app]

Have a look at the generated `document.wflow` inside the app bundle. It's a XML document which you can  programmatically edit to create "apps" for other URLs.

Comment: Thats great! Is it possible to make it frameless?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

WebView!?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003822